# Resizing Background Image depending on browser window

Tags: jquery, css

So I am detecting my width and height no problem with jquery. Now, this may be a simple question but, how can I give the width and height to the image that is normally 3000x2000.

I am using css to load the image as the background

```
var theDiv = $("#container");
var totalWidth = theDiv.width();

$(theDiv "img").css("width" totalWidth);
```

Is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I did one in css: http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/EdyUE/11/ 
What I did was, I gave every element in the page relative positioning using the '*' universal selector, then made a class (.bg) with absolute positioning, 100% width and height & a negative z-index so it will display below the content.
I used a small image to show you how it stretches to fit the window.

Answer (score 0):

here's a js plugin i've made that resizes your image -
http://drewdahlman.com/labs/javascript/background_js

the GIT project -
https://github.com/DrewDahlman/background.js

that will hit all browsers.
just wrap your image in a div with and id of background, and include the script in your $(document).ready function call background.init() and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSS to load the image as background, changing the size of the DIV will not affect the size of the image. You have two choices:

1. Place the image inside your body tag, using absolute positioning, z-index:0 and setting top, left,right and bottom properties to zero.
2. Using CSS3 property **background-size**. For example `body { background-image:url(your_image.png); background-size:cover; }` will scale the image to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area. You can read more at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

I hope this helps!